# Prove $\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{t^2-2tx+1}}dx=\int_{-1}^1 e^{\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\exp(-x)dx}{\sqrt{t^2-2tx+1}}=\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right)dx$$
for $t>0$.

I tried working through an answer to a question (answered by Jack D'Aurizio) in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777189/about-the-fourier-legendre-series-of-fx-e-x).
I am unable to show that:
$$
\overset{1}{\underset{-1}{\int }}\frac{\exp (-x) dx}{\sqrt{t^2-2 \text{tx}+1}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } t^n \left(\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x) \, dx\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{t}} \left[e \ F\left(\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)-e^{-1}F\left(\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)\right] \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Where $F(x)$ is [the Dawson integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) and $P_n(x)e^{-x}$ is the $n^{th}$ [Legendre Polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html). 
I have been able to show that:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{t}} \left[e \ F\left(\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)-e^{-1}F\left(\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)\right] = \int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right)dx \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

For $t>0$ and I detail how I did so in the Post Script. Since \eqref{2} reduces the problem to proving that:

$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\exp(-x)dx}{\sqrt{t^2-2tx+1}}=\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right)dx \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

my question is whether \eqref{3} can be shown without going through \eqref{2} and \eqref{1}, or if there is an intuitive way of showing \eqref{1}.

I am sure there are plenty of derivations out there for \eqref{1}, but at the time of writing this, I have not found any and I have no idea how to use the middle term in \eqref{1} since the integrands on either side of \eqref{3} are different. So any directory information to an article on that would be appreciated.

Post Script:

One can readily obtain:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{t}} \left(e\cdot F\left(\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)-\frac{1}{e}\cdot F\left(\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{t}}\exp \left(-\frac{t^2+1}{2 t}\right)\left(\overset{\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\underset{0}{\int }}-\overset{\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\underset{0}{\int }}\right)e^{y^2}dy
$$

And then identify

$$
\left(\overset{\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\underset{0}{\int }}-\overset{\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\underset{0}{\int }}\right)e^{y^2}dy=\overset{\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\underset{\frac{1-t}{\sqrt{2 t}}}{\int }}e^{y^2} dy \ ; \ t>0
$$

And then substitute:

$$
x=\left(y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2}{t}} \ , \ dy=\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}dx
$$

And then readily obtain \eqref{2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $y=-\frac{t x^2}{2}+\frac{t}{2}-x$. Then, $dx = -\frac1{xt+1}dy$
$$x= \frac1t\left(-1+\sqrt{t^2-2t y+1}\right)\implies 
xt+1= \sqrt{t^2-2t y+1}
$$
and

$$\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right)dx
= \int_{-1}^1\frac{\exp(-y)}{xt+1}dy
= \int_{-1}^1\frac{\exp(-y)}{\sqrt{t^2-2ty+1}}dy
$$

Comment: MUCH better. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have something and am open to comments and criticisms from actual mathematicians.
Show that:

$$
\overset{1}{\underset{-1}{\int }}\frac{e^{-x} dx}{\sqrt{t^2-2 \text{tx}+1}}=\overset{1}{\underset{-1}{\int }}dx \exp \left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right) \ ; \ t>0 \tag{0.1}\label{0.1}
$$

First of all, you can use Mathematica to expand both sides in a power series of (t) and check to see that the equality is true for "large" orders of (t). However, I think it worthwhile to build a method so that one could conceivably do this "by hand" with 3-or-so sheets of paper or create a routine in Mathematica which only involves elementary functions and tabulated values for only the most special functions (in this case, we use the Legendre Polynomials).
Let' s define :

$$
A(x)\equiv \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{t^2-2 \text{tx}+1}} \ , \ B(x)\equiv \exp \left(\frac{t x^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}+x\right) \tag{0.2}\label{0.2}
$$

We will use the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2 \text{tx}+1}} \ $ is the generating function of the Legendre Polynomials (see \eqref{1.1} ) to directly compute $\int_{-1}^1 A(x) \, dx$ and we will grind out a power series in (x) for $B(x)$ and then directly compute $\int_{-1}^1 B(x) \, dx$.

$$
\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{t^2-2 \text{tx}+1}}=e^{-x} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } t^n P_n(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{generating} \text{LegendreP}) \tag{1.1}\label{1.1}
$$
Now we start directly computing the left-hand-side of \eqref{0.1}:
$$
\int _{-1}^1e^{-x} dx \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } t^n  P_n(x) 
$$
Recall:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 e^{-x} x^n \, dx=\left[\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{m+1} e^{-x} n! x^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}\right]_{x=-1}^{x=1} \tag{2.2}\label{2.2}
$$
Now, using tabulated [Legendre Polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) (and skipping much computation):

$$
A(x)=O(t^5)+\left(36 e-\frac{266}{e}\right) t^4+\left(5 e-\frac{37}{e}\right) t^3+\left(e-\frac{7}{e}\right) t^2-\frac{2 t}{e}+2 \sinh (1) \tag{2.3}\label{2.3}
$$

Now, for the right-hand-side. Let's think of a possibly-nice way to take the $n^{th}$ derivative of $B(x)$. Let's define:

$$
G_N\equiv (tx+1)^N \tag{3.1}\label{3.1}
$$

See that:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}B(x)=G_1 B(x) \ \ , \ \ \frac{d}{dx}G_N B(x)=B(x) \left(G_{N+1}+tNG_{N-1}\right) \tag{3.2}\label{3.2}
$$

And see that \eqref{3.2} generates a triangle:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
    \cdot & G_0 B(x) & G_1 B(x) & G_2 B(x) & G_3 B(x) & G_4 B(x) \\
    \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^0\to & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^1\to  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\to  & t & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^3\to  & 0 & 3t & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
    \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^4\to  & 3t^2 & 0 & 6t & 0 & 1  \\
\end{array}
\right) \text{and rows 6+}
$$

And when we consider our inevitable goal of a power series in (x) for $B(x) \ \ $ [$\left(G_N B(x)\right)_{x=0}=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}$] and then integrating from -1 to 1, we see that the triangle becomes:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
    \cdot&e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2}& e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2}&e^{-t/2} \\
    \frac{x^0}{0!}\to \frac{1^1-(-1)^1}{1!}&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \frac{x^1}{1!}\to \frac{1^2-(-1)^2}{2!}&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \frac{x^2}{2!}\to \frac{1^3-(-1)^3}{3!}&t&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \frac{x^3}{3!}\to \frac{1^4-(-1)^4}{4!}&0&3t&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
    \frac{x^4}{4!}\to \frac{1^5-(-1)^5}{5!}&3t^2&0&6t&0&1&0&0&0\\
    \frac{x^5}{5!}\to \frac{1^6-(-1)^6}{6!}&0&15t^2&0&10t&0&1&0&0\\
    \frac{x^6}{6!}\to \frac{1^7-(-1)^7}{7!}&15t^3&0&45t^2&0&15t&0&1&0\\
    \frac{x^7}{7!}\to \frac{1^8-(-1)^8}{8!}&0&105t^3&0&105t^2&0&21t&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right) \text{and rows 9+}
$$

We can see from the first diagonal (all ones $\cdot e^{-t/2}$ ) that the $t^0$ term is $2\sinh (1)$ as in \eqref{2.3}. We need to look at both the first diagonal and second diagonal for the $t^1$ term and indeed:

$$
2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 n^2-n}{(2 n+1)!}-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 n+1)!}=-\frac{2}{e} \tag{3.4}\label{3.4}
$$

Now, I did not show how to evaluate the sums in \eqref{3.4} [though the right hand sum is readily identified as $\sinh (1)$] and I will have to leave that for a different article. Also, I stop here and trust Mathematica for the higher terms.

Comment: For one of the sums in (3.4), you are going to want to identify: 2n²-n=(2n+1)(n-1)+1 and then later identify: n/(2n!) = ½∙(2n)/[(2n)!]. It is mostly sinh and cosh from there